# Make rotation stop realisticly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, sprite-kit, rotation

I have a `square = SKSpriteNode()` that turns that rotates 360° when you touch it. I want to stop the spinning when you touch it again. 
Now I would make `square` rotate through the `SKAction.rotate` but how can I stop the spinning realisticly meaning that I want the sprite to spin slower and slower until it stands still.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try and ease out curve for the [timingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417807-timingmode)?  If you don't like this effect you can provide your own custom [timingFunction](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skaction/1417666-timingfunction).  There are several websites where you can explore animation curves online.  I like [this one.](http://cubic-bezier.com/)

Comment: As grateful as I am for your answer, I do not have a clue how to implement `timingMode`. Could you provide some code by chance?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider using a physicsbody  and applying an angular force.

```
let square = SKSpriteNode(color:.white,size:CGSize(10,10))
if let physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:square.frame.size)
{
   physicsBody.isDynamic = true
   physicsBody.allowsRotation = true
   physicsBody.affectedByGravity = false
   physicsBody.angularDamping  = 0.1 //Adjust this to speed up or slow down the resistance of the spin 
   square.physicsBody = physicsBody
}
```

...

When you need to spin:

```
square.physicsBody!.angularImpulse(1) //Adjust this to change the amount of force applied to the spin
```